# Is it possible to set an account wide auto responder in Google Apps for Business (G Suite) Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

Is it possible to set a company wide auto responder in Google apps for business Gmail?

For instance if the office is closed for a set date range I would like to set an auto responder for all emails, but ideally I don't want to have to set them manually on each email.

Answer (score 1):

A Group does not have this feature directly. You will need to use a user account that is a member of that group which has posting permissions and receiving all messages. Then you can set a canned response on those messages.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to set : `From: *` and also set date start and date end parameters ?

Comment: Out of office only has a start and end date feature but you can leverage gam to schedule a filter to be removed at a certain time along with at for example.

Comment: what is "gam" ?

Comment: gam - https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD/wiki

Comment: at - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-schedule-tasks-using-at-command-on-linux